# Topology: Boundary of boundary

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that

for any $S\subset\mathrm{R^\mathrm{n}}$,  $\partial\partial\mathrm{S}\subset\partial\mathrm{S}$ ,

using the concept of 'open ball'?

#### Progress

For every open ball on any $x \in S$, intersection of $B(r,x)$ and $\partial S$ is non-empty. But I can't seem to proceed towards the definition of $\partial S$ from there.

Comment: Have you tried definition? Let $x  \in \partial\partial S\implies\ldots$

Comment: I did. For every open ball on any x in S, intersection of B(r,x) and ds is non-empty. But I can't seem to proceed towards the definition of ds  from there.

Answer (score 1):

$x \in \partial (\partial S) \iff \boxed{\forall \epsilon >0 , B(x,\epsilon)\cap \partial S \neq \emptyset} $ and $B(x,\epsilon)\cap (\partial S)^C \neq\emptyset $.

Assume that $x \notin \partial S\implies x\in (\partial S )^C$.

Due to the fact $\partial S $ is always a closed set$\implies (\partial S)^C $ is open.

That means $\exists \epsilon_0>0$, s.t. $B(x,\epsilon_0)\subset (\partial S)^C $, which means  $B(x,\epsilon_0)\cap \partial S=\emptyset$, which is absurdum, due to  the box.

Comment: There is a problem with this proof. Applying the same procedure to (ds)complement, this would mean x is in the complement too isn't it?

Comment: Answer edited...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $x \in \partial \partial S$, then **any** open ball around $x$ contains some point in $\partial S$ and some point not in $\partial S$. Fix $r>0$. Choose some $y \in B(\frac{r}{2},x) \cap \partial S$. Can you now show that in $B(r,x)$ there is some point in $S$ and some point not in $S$?